# Groupby, apply function to each row with shift, and create new column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group by `id`, apply a function to the data, and create a new column with the results. It seems there must be a faster/more efficient way to do this than to pass the data to the function, make the changes, and return the data. Here is an example.

**Example**

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'x': [4, 8, 12, 25, 30, 50]})

def my_func(data):
    data['diff'] = (data['x'] - data['x'].shift(1, fill_value=data['x'].iat[0]))
    return data

dat.groupby('id').apply(my_func)
```

**Output**

```
> print(dat)


id  x   diff
0   a   4   0
1   a   8   4
2   a   12  4
3   b   25  0
4   b   30  5
5   b   50  20
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What you want to do then , different situation may have different solutions .

Comment: @Wen-Ben I am wanting to apply a general function to a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.groupby.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for this and after that fill the `NaN` with zero like following:

```
dat['diff'] = dat.groupby('id').x.diff().fillna(0)

print(dat)
  id   x  diff
0  a   4   0.0
1  a   8   4.0
2  a  12   4.0
3  b  25   0.0
4  b  30   5.0
5  b  50  20.0
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is related to applying a function in general, not only diff.

Comment: @Vedda Perhaps you should have been clearer about this in the question. You asked "Is there a more efficient way to do this", and this answers it perfectly (at least as originally asked - I see you've edited the question)

Comment: Functions are in general slower than vectorized solutions, so if you have the option not to use function, you should not. Besides that, if you definitely want to use a function, yours looks fine.

Comment: @AndrewGuy Yes, you are correct. I've updated the question to be more general. This solution certainly works and I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @Erfan Thanks, I need custom calculations so I need custom functions. In `R`, `dplyr` handles this really well but it seems pandas is much slower.

Comment: Can I ask what the calcultion exactly is? Because in most cases there are vectorized solutions available.

Comment: @Erfan Calculating the difference in time between a timestamp and shift(1). Also, calculating spherical distances between timestamp and shift(1) using lat/long. They are certainly custom and I have many more.

Comment: The first one can be done with the solution above. But I see your point. Good luck and the calculations sound interesting :)